# Append an Array to an Unordered List

Tags: javascript, arrays, markup

What I'm trying to accomplish with this code is to output the array `alphabet` as a series of list items into an existing unordered list in the actual markup. I've got the array into list items, but I can't figure out how to tell it to append itself to an existing unordered list `<ul id="itemList"></ul>`.

```
var itemsExist = true;
var indexNum = 0;
var unorderedList = document.getElementById('itemList');
var alphabet= new Array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");

function write_letters(){

    for (i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++ ) {
        document.write('<li>'  + alphabet[indexNum++] + '</li>');
    }

}

if (itemsExist){
    write_letters();
} else {
    document.write("error!");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `document.write` to do it. You should act like this:

```
function write_letters(){
    var letters = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++ ) {
        //Also I don't understand the purpose of the indexNum variable.
        //letters += "<li>"  + alphabet[indexNum++] + "</li>";
        letters += "<li>"  + alphabet[i] + "</li>";
    }

    document.getElementById("itemList").innerHTML = letters;
}
```

More proper way is to use DOM (in case you want full control of what's coming on):

```
function write_letters(){
    var items = document.getElementById("itemList");

    for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++ ) {
        var item = document.createElement("li");
        item.innerHTML = alphabet[i];
        items.appendChild(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly; I'll do some reading on `.innerHTML`. The purpose of indexNum was a sort of hackish way to increment the index value of the array. Looking at your code its obvious that i was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of createElement() and appendChild() to add new HTML elements within another HTML element. The code below should work for you:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Script Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="itemList"></ul>
</body>

<script>
    var itemsExist = true;
    var indexNum = 0;
    var unorderedList = document.getElementById('itemList');
    var alphabet= new Array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
    var myElement;

    function write_letters(){

        for (i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++ ) {
            // Create the <LI> element
            myElement = document.createElement("LI");
            // Add the letter between the <LI> tags
            myElement.innerHTML = alphabet[indexNum++];
            // Append the <LI> to the bottom of the <UL> element
            unorderedList.appendChild(myElement);
        }
    }

    if (itemsExist){
        write_letters();
    } else {
        document.write("error!");
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Note how the script exists below the body tag. This is important if you want your script to work the way you wrote it. Otherwise document.getElementById('itemList') will not find the 'itemList' ID.

Comment: If you're going to be using the DOM, you should also use text nodes (`myElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(alphabet[indexNum++]))`) instead of innerHTML. Also, for XHTML compatibility, you'd want to use `li` instead of `LI` in your `createElement` call.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reduce the actions on the DOM as much as possible. Every appendChild on `unorderedList` forces the browser to re-render the complete page. Use [documentFragement](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) for that sort of action.

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = alphabet.length; i--; ) {
   var li = document.createElement("li");
   li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(alphabet[indexNum++]));
   frag.appendChild(li);
}
unorderedList.appendChild(frag);
```

So there will be only one DOM action which forces a complete redraw instead of `alphabet.length` redraws

Comment: This should be number one. I have never seen or heard of this before.